# Polymer WCT - Browser chrome not found in ubuntu

Tags: polymer-1.0, web-component-tester

Just have polymer starter kit up and running in Ubuntu, trying to run the tests after installing the Java and had chrome installed already.

I have configured to run the tests with chrome (as tests with firefox is failing),
when i run the command "gulp test" i am getting below error

'wct:local' errored after 367 ms
   Error: The following browsers were not found: chrome. (All installed
   browsers found: firefox)

Not sure what i am missing here, 
wct.conf.js

```html
  "plugins": {
    "local": {
      "browsers": ["chrome"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just installing the chrome again worked fine.

The version of chrome browser i had installed was **Chromium**,
which installed through the Ubuntu software center.

This causes WCT not recognizing this browser.